# Choose ng-template reference in a function and return it to ngTemplateOutlet?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 20 different `ng-templates` in my component. Depending on some `@Input()`, one `ng-template` should be chosen and rendered inside a `ng-container`. A function will check what is the proper template to choose and should return that result to the `*ngTemplateOutlet` of my `ng-container`. Also, the `ng-container` is inside a `ngFor`, so there will multiple different templates chosen depending on input. Here's a quick overview of what the strcture is like:

```
<table> 
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of data; let rowIndex = index">
            <td *ngFor="let column of columns; let colIndex = index">
                <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="getComponentForType(colIndex)">
                </ng-container>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> 
</table>

<ng-template #typeabcTemplate> some content here </ng-template>
<ng-template #typedefTemplate> some content here </ng-template>
```

There would be 18 more `ng-template`s after this.

My problem is that I need a way for the method `getComponentForType()` to return which template to use. I tried returning a string representing the variable of the template, but that didn't work. It seems that I need to return a template-ref, but that also seems to cause some issues. I cannot use `@ViewChild` since that I have 20 templates, so I have to use `@ViewChildren`. The problem is that this doesn't seem to properly get references to my templates. I just get a big list of 30 items. I have no way of getting the variable names of my ng-templates nor to return them.

How can I go about this?

Comment: Could you provide more code? What is the current implementation of `getComponentForType()` function?

Comment: You can use `@ViewChildren(TemplateRef) templates:QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>`

Comment: @Eliseo Yes, that is what I am currently using. The problem is that I cannot find a way to identify my TemplateRefs. Is there a way to access to variable associated with the template ref or assign it some sort of ID?

Comment: @ThomasFromUganda, sorry I was in hurry and only comment an idea. Really I don't get much more, I answer a work-around but I don't like so much :(

Answer (score 1):

I try to use `@ViewChildren(TemplateRef) templates:QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>`, but I can not know the template. Well, the QueryList are ordered by position, so the first is the first ng-template, the second one, the second template

```
const templateRef=this.templates.toArray(index)
```

You always can make an ungly work around that is enclosed each template by a div

```
<div id="1">
   <ng-template  #typeabcTemplate> some content here </ng-template>
</div>
<div id="2">
   <ng-template  #typedefTemplate> some content here </ng-template>
</div>
```

And you can know the "id", and find the template by the id of the parent e.g.

```
const templateRef=this.templates.find(
     x=>x.elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement
                        .getAttribute('id')=='1')
```

NOTE1: remember that your function must return a templateRef, not a string

NOTE2: Always I make an ugly work-around I think that must be a better way to solution the problem, perhafs a switchCase

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'll try to see if I can have a workaround with IDs!

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

If you need full blown components I recommend creating a directive that generates components. You would put this directive on an ng-template and it would actually end up creating a component on the template where the directive is located. You can pass the component properties as well! I used a similar method to create dynamic forms as well as entire dynamic pages, but that's a different story.

https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

You would have a map that designates the components based on a particular value and create components in the directive

```
 @Directive({
  selector: '[appDynamicField]'
})
export class DynamicFieldDirective implements OnInit {

@Input() type
@Input() foo; // some random property you want to give the generated component.

// map for components
components = {
foo1: myFoo1Component, // myFoo1Component would be an actual component you create
foo2: myFoo2Component
}
 ngOnInit(){
  const component = this.components[this.type];
      const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<any>(component);
      this.component = this.container.createComponent(factory);
      this.component.instance.foo = this.foo; // giving the component data that you have in this directive. It can be from your data array or anything really...
}
```

And then for your template use:

```
 <ng-container 
      appDynamicField
      [foo]="data" // you can pass it the whole data object if you want.
      [type]="data[colIndex][rowIndex]>
```

....

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a viable option since that I have 20 templates. I can't have 20 `ViewChild`s, so I need a way that doesn't make me manually write all 20 `ViewChild`s.

Comment: I usually opt for a component library such as angular-material and use their table with it's api to get what I'm looking for. If you aren't doing a full blown component and just want text you could simply use string interpolation and have a map where you have an object with keys that == the data at a given coordinate and the text you need for it.

Comment: If you need full blown components I recommend creating a directive that generates components.
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

you would have a map that designates the components based on a particular value and create components in the directive
@Input() type
components = {
foo1: myFoo1Component,
foo2: myFoo2Component
}
 ngOnInit(){
  const component = this.components[this.type];
      const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<any>(component);
      this.component = this.container.createComponent(factory);
}